# Safe backup/restore of Linux partitions in a Windows /Linux dual boot setup using a recovery partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, multi-boot, reinstall

I have a dual-boot laptop (Windows 7/Kubuntu 12.04) with an IDE spinning-rust disk.

I'd like to reinstall Windows. The problem is that the only medium for that is a factory-installed recovery partition, and I'm concerned it might potentially damage the Linux partitions.

My current plan of attack is:

1. Note down existing partition information (from e.g. `parted`).
2. Back up the Linux partitions using `dd`.
3. Use the Windows recovery to reinstall Windows.
4. If the recovery process damages the Linux partitions or dual boot configuration, use a LiveCD to:

   1. Partition the disk as it was before the reinstall.
   2. Use `dd` to write the partition data into the newly created partitions.
   3. Restore the dual boot configuration (I have yet to research how I go about that).

The question I'd like to ask: **is this the correct approach, and, if yes, what are the gaps and potential pitfalls I should be mindful about?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably will damage the linux partitions and any other partitions (so back up to an external, detachable disk), if it's anything like what I've dealt with before; good news is you do have a solid plan of attack. However, you might also want to back up your boot loader (probably GRUB), which is stored in the first 446 bytes of the drive:

```
dd of=/backup/bootloader.mbr if=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

And then restore it after you replace the partitions

```
dd of=/dev/sda if=/backup/bootloader.mbr
```

Alternatively, I think you can use a live CD to boot the linux partition, and then

```
sudo update-grub
```

to re-write the bootloader.

Comment: So I'm on the right track, then? Thanks for the GRUB instructions. One question 'though - why this specific byte buffer (466) in `dd`?

Comment: OK, since this answer has gone unaccepted for too long, I'll assume this is just for convention's sake.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Whoops, I missed the notification about your comment: The first 512 bytes of a DOS-formatted harddrive (as opposed to Apple or GPT) are the bootloader and partition table. Specifically, the first 466 are the boot loader, and then 467-512 are the partition table. Since we just want the boot loader, we set the block size to 466 and tell `dd` to copy 1 block. "Disk Convention" isn't the right word for it (though it is a convention I suppose); "Disk Format" better describes it.

Comment: heh, I also had a brainfart and missed the `count=1` bit and hence the entire point of the command. Thanks for the clarification. I suggest it would be worthwhile to edit it into the answer. BTW, I think you might have probably meant `446` instead of `466`:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record#Sector_layout .

Comment: Indeed I did; Fixed!